# Почему не удается изменить данные родителя при наследовании?

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Проблема такая: у меня есть класс родитель

```
MainWindow
```

От него есть класс который наследуется от родительского  `Add`
У класса `MainWindow` есть переменная int y и кнопка на форме, кнопка
должна вызвать метод  `addSetInt()`  класса `add`
который в свою очередь должен изменить переменную (`y` или любые другие доступные данные класса `MainWindow`). Так вот проблема в том что отладчик qt
просто при указывает при обращении к переменной родительского класса на
эту переменную стрелкой. Все... никаких ни ошибок ничего, просто все
вылетает и указывает на попытку изменить переменную родительского класса
без каких либо намеков

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void setInt(int value)
    {
        y=value;  // именно сюда указывает стрелка отладчика
    }

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int y;
};

#endif // MA
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "add.h"

add* d;  // создем экземляр класса add

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    d->addSetInt();   /* по нажатию кнопки на форме я хочу
                     что бы изменилась переменная int (y этого же 
класса)*/
}
```

add.h:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
#include "mainwindow.h"

class add : public MainWindow
{
public:

    void addSetInt();

};

#endif // ADD_H
```

add.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"

void add::addSetInt()
{
    MainWindow::setInt(1);  /* обращаюсь к методу родительского . 
класса*/
}
```

Comment: Приведите код где создается экземпляр этого класса и вызываете этот метод.  `add* d;  // создем экземляр класса add` выглядит подозрительно, потому что 1) глобальная переменная 2) никакого экземпляра тут не создается.

Comment: значит я туплю... а как тогда можно мне публично использовать этот класс и/или правильно создать его экземпляр для этого? можно пожалуйста пример того как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: В qt creator в создании формы можно добавить кастомный класс и использовать его. В Гугле это есть.

Comment: это точно то что мне нужно? по моему кастомные классы не решат проблемы, мне всего то нужно через другой класс получить доступ к родительскому (в принципе наверно неважно как)

Comment: Конструктор вашего обьекта сначала конструирует базовый класс, но  конструктор базового класса определен позже ...  Попробуйте обьявить обьект после определения конструктора  базового класса

Comment: @AR пробовал, или такая же история или вообще QWidget ругается на то что создаем какие либо объекты до app.exec()

Comment: аргумент конструктора QWidget *parent   не имеет значение по умолчанию, присвойте ноль

Answer (score 2):

Вы просто не создали объект `add`. У вас в переменная `d` это указатель на `add` правильно, но этот указатель содержит мусор, так как сам объект еще нужно создать. Например так:

```
add * d = new add();
```